# XSLT - How do I convert a vertical dataset to a horizontal data set with defined headers

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert a vertical data set to a horizontal data set.

Data Set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Export>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>1</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>A</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>Scottie</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>E</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>306.83</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>71.76</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>Main</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>Main</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>0.00</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>2</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>B</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>Michael</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>L</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>311.78</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>72.92</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>Main</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>Main</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>0.00</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward></D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>3</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>C</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>Kelly</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>D</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>353.03</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>82.56</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>Main</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>Main</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>0.00</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>4</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>D</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>Janet</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>A</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>Main</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>Main</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>0.00</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>4</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>D</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>Janet</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>A</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>County</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>FrdrckCoW/H</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>27.42</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>5</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>E</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>John</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>E</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>Main</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>Main</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>0.00</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>5</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>E</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>John</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>E</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>County</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>WashCoW/H-MD</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>163.18</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>6</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>F</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>Todd</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>E</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>709.69</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>165.98</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>Main</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>Main</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>0.00</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>6</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>F</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>Todd</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>E</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>709.69</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>165.98</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>Township</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>BtlrTwpW/H-L</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>120.00</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
        <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>7</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>G</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>Melissa</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>L</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>Main</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>Main</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>0.00</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <D_EmployeeNumber>7</D_EmployeeNumber>
        <D_LastName>G</D_LastName>
        <D_FirstName>Melissa</D_FirstName>
        <D_MiddleName>L</D_MiddleName>
        <D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_SocSecYTDWHAmt>
        <D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>0.00</D_MedicareYTDWHAmt>
        <D_WHType>County</D_WHType>
        <D_WHName>FrdrckCoW/H</D_WHName>
        <D_WHAmt>122.74</D_WHAmt>
        <D_EquityAward>True</D_EquityAward>
    </Record>
    </Export>
```

I have tried so many things my eyes are popping out.

Here is my latest XSLT

```
    <xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0"
                 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:vb="urn:the-xml-files:xslt-vb"
                xmlns:cs="urn:cs">


    <msxsl:script language="VBScript" implements-prefix="vb" >
      <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO"/>


    <![CDATA[               

       ]]>

    </msxsl:script>
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="CountyRecords">
            <Records>
                <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[(D_EquityAward = 'True' and D_WHType ='County' and D_WHAmt != 0.00)]"> <!-- Only County and Equity -->
                    <Record>
                        <xsl:element name="EmpNumber">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="D_EmployeeNumber"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="CountyWHName">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="D_WHName"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </Record>         
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Records>
    </xsl:variable> 

        <xsl:variable name="CityRecords">
            <Records>
                <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[(D_EquityAward = 'True' and D_WHType ='City' and D_WHAmt != 0.00)]"> <!-- Only County and Equity -->
                    <Record>
                        <xsl:element name="EmpNumber">
                            <xsl:value-of select="D_EmployeeNumber"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="CityWHName">
                            <xsl:value-of select="D_WHName"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </Record>         
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Records>
    </xsl:variable> 

        <xsl:variable name="BoroughRecords">
            <Records>
                <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[(D_EquityAward = 'True' and D_WHType ='Borough' and D_WHAmt != 0.00)]"> <!-- Only County and Equity -->
                    <Record>
                        <xsl:element name="EmpNumber">
                            <xsl:value-of select="D_EmployeeNumber"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="BoroughWHName">
                            <xsl:value-of select="D_WHName"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </Record>         
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Records>
    </xsl:variable> 

        <xsl:variable name="TownshipRecords">
            <Records>
                <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[(D_EquityAward = 'True' and D_WHType ='Township' and D_WHAmt != 0.00)]"> <!-- Only County and Equity -->
                    <Record>
                        <xsl:element name="EmpNumber">
                            <xsl:value-of select="D_EmployeeNumber"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="TownshipWHName">
                            <xsl:value-of select="D_WHName"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </Record>         
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Records>
    </xsl:variable> 


     <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[(D_EquityAward = 'True' and D_WHType ='Main')]">
            <xsl:value-of select="D_EmployeeNumber"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="D_LastName"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="D_FirstName"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="D_MiddleName"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="(./D_EmployeeNumber= msxsl:node-set($CountyRecords)/Records/Record/EmpNumber)">
                <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($CountyRecords)/Records/Record/CountyWHName" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="(./D_EmployeeNumber = msxsl:node-set($CityRecords)/Records/Record/EmpNumber)">
                <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($CityRecords)/Records/Record/CityWHName" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="(./D_EmployeeNumber = msxsl:node-set($TownshipRecords)/Records/Record/EmpNumber)">
                <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($TownshipRecords)/Records/Record/TownshipWHName" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="(./D_EmployeeNumber = msxsl:node-set($BoroughRecords)/Records/Record/EmpNumber)">
                <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($BoroughRecords)/Records/Record/BoroughWHName" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>                           
            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Expected Results:

```
1,A,Scottie,E,,,,
3,C,Kelly,D,,,,
4,D,Janet,A,FrdrckCoW/H,,,
5,E,John,E,WashCoW/H-MD,,,
6,F,Todd,E,,,WashCoW/H-MD,
7,G,Melissa,L,FrdrckCoW/H,,,
```

---

What I did here was create Node Sets based on each Tax Type and then in my final For Each link them to the specific node set if the employee has one of those tax types.

The issue that I have doing it this way is I only get the value in the first line of my node set.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thank you - Steve

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with all the code (XML, XSLT, expected result) included in the question **as code**.

Comment: I have updated the question to include an XML snipit and the expected results using that xml data.

Comment: FWIW, I pasted your code here https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvN and I am getting the expected result. Perhaps you're not using a Microsoft processor?

Comment: When you ran it did you get the correct Counties for the employees?  When I run it everybody that is supposed to have a County gets one but hey all get the same one.

Comment: Why are you asking me, when you have the link and can see for yourself? I don't know what the correct counties are. I think your code is horrendously overcomplicated, but it does not return the result you report.

Comment: I clicked on the link and it is giving everybody the first County that it comes to.  In the XML I changed the county name for the first person that had one and it changed everybody to that one.  If there is a less complicated way to get make this work I would like to know.

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvN/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there is a less complicated way to get make this work I would like to know.

It's hard to work from a single example (that doesn't even return the expected result), without a clear statement of the logic that needs to be applied here. I am guessing you want to do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="grp" match="Record[D_EquityAward = 'True' and D_WHAmt != 0]" use="D_EmployeeNumber" />

<xsl:template match="/Export">
    <!-- FOR EACH MAIN RECORD -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Record[D_EquityAward = 'True' and D_WHType ='Main']">
        <!-- COMMON FIELDS -->
        <xsl:value-of select="D_EmployeeNumber"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="D_LastName"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="D_FirstName"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="D_MiddleName"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <!-- DATA FROM OTHER RECORDS OF THIS EMPLOYEE: -->
        <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('grp', D_EmployeeNumber)"/>
        <!-- 1. COUNTY NAME -->     
        <xsl:value-of select="$group[D_WHType ='County']/D_WHName"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <!-- 2. CITY NAME -->       
        <xsl:value-of select="$group[D_WHType ='City']/D_WHName"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <!-- 3. TOWNSHIP NAME -->       
        <xsl:value-of select="$group[D_WHType ='Township']/D_WHName"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>      
        <!-- 4. BOROUGH NAME -->        
        <xsl:value-of select="$group[D_WHType ='Borough']/D_WHName"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>                           
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result when applied to your input example will be:

```
1,A,Scottie,E,,,,
3,C,Kelly,D,,,,
4,D,Janet,A,XFrdrckCoW/H,,,
5,E,John,E,WashCoW/H-MD,,,
6,F,Todd,E,,,BtlrTwpW/H-L,
7,G,Melissa,L,FrdrckCoW/H,,,
```

which is different from both your current result and the expected result posted in your question.

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvN/4

Comment: That is exactly what I want it to do.  I realized earlier I posted the wrong result in my question where I accidently pasted the county name in instead of the Township name.  With the updated XML change I made this is the expected result.  THANK YOU